# PHP Expire Session after 5 minutes

Tags: php, session

I have the following code to expire a session after set amount of time. It is however not working properly. If I set it for example for 1 minute or even 5 minute, it expires immediately. Can you help?

```
// duration in minutes * seconds
$duration = (DURATION * 60);

if(isset($_SESSION['started']))
{
    // show banner and hide form
    echo $msg;
    $showform = 0;
    if((time() - $_SESSION['started'] - $duration) > 0)
    {
        unset($_SESSION['count']);
        unset($_SESSION['offender']);
        $showform = 1;
    }
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['started'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Damn Visual Studio! Can't believe I just tried right-clicking `DURATION` in your code snippet and tried to select "Go to Definition". lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified your code little bit take a look. This should work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$duration = (DURATION * 60);

if(isset($_SESSION['started']))
{
    // show banner and hide form

    $showform = 0;
    $time = ($duration - (time() - $_SESSION['started']));
    if($time <= 0)
    {
        unset($_SESSION['count']);
        unset($_SESSION['offender']);
        $showform == 1;
    }
}
else
{
  $_SESSION['started'] = time();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session_cache_expire(5);
$cache_expire = session_cache_expire();
session_start();
echo "The cache limiter is now set to $cache_limiter<br />";
echo "The cached session pages expire after $cache_expire minutes";
```